# Animate text movement in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently when I scroll down my page, the **Home** link `bumps` into place.

How do I animate this, so it moves smoothly for me?

http://jsfiddle.net/pux7v4tL/2/

```js
$(function () {
    $('header').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');
    $('#menu-button').on('click', function () {
        var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
        menuItems.toggle();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#header_nav').data('size', 'small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height: '78px'
            }, 600);
            $("ul#menu-primary-menu").css("top", "35%");
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 600);
            $("ul#menu-primary-menu").css("top", "auto");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#header_nav {
  background: #1588cb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
    height:9000px
}

nav {
    height:100px
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header style="background-color:#1588cb">
    <div id="header_nav">
  <nav class="primary menu">
      <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
              <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @michaelmcgurk for animating positions, it is needed to mention positions in fixed value. (Like: top:50px; etc...)

Comment: @isherwood Sorry :-)

Comment: @divy3993 Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Sure, Posted the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the `ul` position in your demo and forgot to give some transition to that element. You have to give transition to the element for animating it.

I changed some of your jquery code and add transition to the `ul`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pux7v4tL/5/)

Comment: It's great that your answer works, but you need to describe what you did **in the answer**, and not just give a *link-only answer*. Add the changes made mentioned in the answer, they are certainly small enough to do so.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Noted, I'll do.

Answer (score 2):

Changed your positioning of `top` to `bottom` in your **JQuery**, as i mentioned in comment you need to give specific value to whatever positions.

Here i gave `bottom:0px;` into your `else` and `35%` on `scroll>0`.

Also you will need .`animate({....})` for the transition effect.

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/pux7v4tL/6/)</kbd>**

```js
$(function () {
    $('header').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');
    $('#menu-button').on('click', function () {
        var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
        menuItems.toggle();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#header_nav').data('size', 'small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height: '78px'
            }, 600);
            $("ul#menu-primary-menu").animate({"bottom": "35%"}); // Updated
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 600);
            $("ul#menu-primary-menu").animate({"bottom": "0px"}); // Updated
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#header_nav {
  background: #1588cb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
    height:9000px
}

nav {
    height:100px
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header style="background-color:#1588cb">
    <div id="header_nav">
  <nav class="primary menu">
      <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
          <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
              <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```